# Does it make any sense to declare a static variable in a class' function where the object is static

Tags: c++, static, static-members

Lets say my class lets say I have

```
static classA myObject;

void classA::update(int elapsed)
{
  static int sumElapsed = 0;
  sumElapsed+= elapsed;

}
```

It seems that my questions is kind of hard to understand.  But if we say that myObject is a singleton of classA.  Is there a difference between the local static int sumElapsed and a private member int sumElapsed of the classA, other than the scope in which they can get accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. For example in the singleton pattern. There a reference (or pointer) to the static variable is also returned from a static method.

---

For an example see here: [c++ Meyers singleton undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808416/c-meyers-singleton-undefined-reference)

By the way, if you are interested: [Are Singletons really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020312/are-singletons-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want sumElapsed to be overwritten then yes, but it does seem like it would make more sense to have sumElapsed ecapsulated within classA as a static variable.

Comment: Doesn't having the suMelapsed encapsulated within classA as a none-static variable would have the same effect since classA is static?

Comment: No because I think that is a issue with scope. Static declares that the variable remains in memory. The variable would be overwritten every time since it is being set to 0 in the update function. Should only need to be initialized once.

Comment: @Apoc But you don't have `sumElapsed` encapsulated.  You declare it within `update`.  If you also have a class member `classA::sumElapsed`, then the local variable will be hiding it--bad practice.  I think I see your confusion--the solution is to declare `sumElapsed` within `classA`, statically, and just use it within the static method as you would any member.  The compiler will force the static declaration of `sumElapsed` in  this case.

Comment: That's what I suggested to do, Matt. Thanks for the support. :)

Comment: Ha I was switching back and forth between windows, somehow thought that Apoc's comment was a response to my own answer.  Sorry, not trying to horn in on your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, when you need some sort of a static member in a class template there aren't really good alternatives in the first place. Also, if the members aren't trivial you probably want to put them into a function in the first place to have some level of control over the order of initialization.

In general, be aware that whether you put a static member into a class or into a function, it is still effectively implementing the Singleton **anti-pattern**!

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  If `sumElapsed` isn't static, it will get overwritten every time the function is called; as it is, it won't be.  The fact that `classA::update` is itself static is irrelevant; just consider if it was a global function (e.g. in C).

Comment: Made some clarification, I meant that the class A object is static not the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a static class to hold methods that are not associated with a particular object. That being said, use a static class to hold only static members that cannot be instantiated by objects, and shouldn't be overwritten.